# OpenVPN set system proxy of client

Tags: proxy, openvpn

I am connecting to an OpenVPN server and would like to set the system proxy of the connecting client to a particular ip and port combination. So far I could only find a way to set the DNS server ip on the client machine but not the proxy. Is there still a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, IMHO there's still hope:

1) reconfigure OpenVPN to TAP mode (layer 2) and serve wpad.dat settings through ISC DHCPd. Like: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/ProxyAutoConfig

2) use OpenVPN's `redirect-gateway` directive, intercept all HTTP/HTTPS traffic using iptables' marking mechanism and push that traffic to transparent proxy (simultaneous S(p)NAT/D(p)NAT) or just redirect all traffic via openvpn gateway.